# Verifying field automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to compute the Galois group of $p(x) = x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I more or less know how to do it, but I am hung up on one detail. The idea is that $p(x)$ factors as $(x - \omega_1)(x - \omega_2)(x - \omega_3)(x - \omega_4)$, where $\omega_k = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}k}$ for $k = 1, .., 4$. That means the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, where $\omega = \omega_1$. Since $\omega$ is a root of $p(x)$, then the minimal polynomial $m_\omega(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ has degree at most deg$(p(x)) = 4$ (otherwise it wouldn't be minimal). Therefore the degree of the extension $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega) : \mathbb{Q}] \leq 4$. Since $p(x)$ separates into distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, the degree of the extension is exactly equal to the size of the Galois group. So $|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q})| \leq 4$. We can define maps $\sigma_j : \omega \mapsto \omega^j$ that extend linearly to the rest of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ for $j = 1, 2, 3, 4$, and the point is supposed to be that these four maps are supposed to define the entire Galois group, since there are at most four elements, and we have found four.

But my question is, how do we actually see that these maps really are automorphisms? If we actually knew what the degree of the extension was, then we could explicitly write elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ as linear combinations of powers of $\omega$, so that we could verify that each $\sigma_j$ was an automorphism. But as it is, we don't know what the degree of the extension is, other than it is no more than $4$. I can of course just check with a computer to figure out what the degree is, but that defeats the point. How can I be sure that $\omega$ doesn't satisfy some polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree $3$ or less?

Comment: If $\omega$ has a minimal polynomial of degree less than $4$, some of the $\omega_i$ will not be roots of that polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, it felt like I was missing something basic like that. Does this observation only apply here, since the roots are powers of $\omega$, or is this a more general property?

Comment: I'm sorry. Thinking about it, that's not as helpful as I initially thought it was.

Comment: No don’t be sorry it’s still helpful here. We have $0 = \sigma_j(0) = \sigma_j(m_\omega(\omega)) = m_\omega(\sigma_j(\omega)) = m_\omega(\omega^j) = m_\omega(\omega_j)$ for each $j = 1, 2, 3, 4$, so each $\omega_j$ must be a root of the minimal polynomial $m_\omega(x)$, which basically proves $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial. So that definitely helps solve my problem. I am just thinking that this observation won’t be able to be used more generally since we can’t see that every root of the factorization will be a root of the minimal polynomial of a particular root in general. But I am not sure.

Comment: In general the $p$th cyclotomic polynomial, for $p$ a prime, is $x^{p-1} + \ldots + x + 1$ and by definition this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I understand how we could show this is irreducible, since the roots are the $p$-th roots of unity except for $1$, but why are we showing that this is irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the degree were less than $4$. Then $\omega$ would satisfy a monic minimal polynomial $f$ of degree less than $4$. Hence it suffices to check that $p(x)$ is irreducible. There are a few ways.

Firstly, notice that none of the roots you wrote down are rational, hence $p(x)$ has no linear factors. Thus, if $p(x)$ is reducible it must be a product of quadratic factors. Say
\begin{align*}
p(x) &= (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)
\end{align*}
comparing coefficients will give you a system of equations to solve, and you will deduce a contradiction.

A perhaps better way is to consider $p(x + 1)$ (which has a root if and only if $p(x)$ does) and notice that this is Eisenstein for the prime $5$, hence irreducible.

---

**Edit:** In response to the question in the comments. Suppose that $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial $f(x)$ over a field $F$. Then I claim that the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $\alpha$ divides $f(x)$. Why? By the division algorithm
$$f(x) = q(x)p(x) + r(x)$$
where $r$ has degree less than $p$. But $p$ is the *minimal polynomial* hence $r(\alpha)$ is nonzero, or $r(x) = 0$. But $f(\alpha) = p(\alpha) = 0$, so it must be the second case, and $p$ divides $f$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense for how you showed $p(x)$ is irreducible. I would not have found that second method. But I am still not sure why it suffices to show $p(x)$ is irreducible in the first place. Why couldn't the minimal polynomial just be something completely unrelated to $p(x)$?

Comment: @t42d Don't worry - the second method is just a trick everyone learns at some point when finding out about cyclotomic polynomials. I have updated my answer to answer your second query.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had completely forgotten about using the division algorithm to show this. So if I am interpreting this correctly, does this mean that in general if we want to show a polynomial $f(x)$ with root $\alpha$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, it suffices to show $f$ is irreducible (and monic)? If it isn't irreducible, then it isn't minimal, and if it is irreducible, then since the minimal polynomial divides it, then $f$ must itself be the minimal polynomial.